# How to write AOP @Around for a package from specific dependency

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I have multiple packages with same name like `org.abc.com.client.*` in different external libraries/dependencies which have same `groupId` name but unique `artifactId` name.

Therefore, it looks like:

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>same_name</groupId>  
  <artifactId>unique</artifactId>  
  <version>same_or_different</version>   
</dependency>
```

and unique artifactId has same package name. I don't need AOP for a class.

I want write `@Around` for a package specific to particular `artifactId`.

```
@Around("call(* package(org.abc.com.client)_of_specific_artifactId1(..))")
public void doSomething(){}

@Around("call(* package(org.abc.com.client)_of_specific_artifactId2(..))")
public void logSomething(){}
```

Comment: Is `artifcatId` the only disitinguishing factor for the classes ? With Spring AOP this appears to be not possible.

Comment: Yes, I see ```artifactId``` only as distinguishing factor for package.

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback. It is not polite to ask a question and then not react to answers. If I was able to answer your question, please also accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: @kriegaex I am aware of your answer, however, I have to test it out. I am not just working on fixing this. I do work on other issue as well. I have to implement it in kotlin project. Please keep patience. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The artifact ID is a piece of build-time information and should be utterly irrelevant during runtime. BTW, artifact IDs can change, dependencies be re-packaged into uber JARs via Maven Shade or Maven Assembly plugins etc. What you want to do is simply bad design. You should refactor your libraries or find another way to differentiate them from each other.

FWIW, you can solve your problem also during build time by applying **native AspectJ** aspects to selected artifacts using **binary weaving**, creating new woven artifacts which can replace the original ones. The AspectJ Maven plugin [does that for you](https://dev-aspectj.github.io/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveJars.html), if configured correctly. For Gradle have a look at Freefair.

---

**Update:** About 7 years ago, I [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26523832/1082681) involving binary weaving of input JARs. It is a more complex multi-module scenario and if you read the whole answer, you are also going to find a link to a GitHub repository with a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just replace the the Maven plugin `org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7` by `dev.aspectj:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.13`, because the MojoHaus version only supports up to Java 8 and misses some features compared the [Aspectj.dev version](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin).

Comment: Note: "What you want to do is simply bad design", these are not my libraries first of all, I couldn't make changes to the libraries. I am using latest version of kotlin with spring boot in startup project. I am not sure it works for me though thank you for your reply. I will give a try.

Comment: Aso, It may not be worth to integrate AOP in kotlin spring-boot project until this (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22462) gets fixed.

Comment: You are mixing up topics. I am talking about native AspectJ, the Spring issue is about Spring AOP, so AspectJ is not affected by it. Furthermore, your example code uses `call` pointcuts which are unavailable in Spring AOP. Therefore, I was assuming you want to use AspectJ anyway and knew the difference.

Comment: I am using ```io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving  version 6.0.0-m2``` as gradle plugin, ```implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.6``` and ```implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.6``` as dependencies. Someway I have to solve this problem. I think I can extract some knowledge from your answer. Here, the ```call``` pointcut works.

Comment: If you would simply post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - ideally on GitHub - instead of fragmentary code snippets and information in comments one week after asking the actual question, I could help you better. Like I said, if `call` works for you, you are using AspectJ, and the Spring issue you are waiting for is about Spring AOP, not about AspectJ. Can you debug what you cannot see? I cannot. So show me something, if you want a more specific answer. But what I wrote is the correct solution, just adapt if from Maven to Gradle.